# Cardinality of transcendental numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello everyone I'm struggling to prove that $|T|=|R|$, where $T$ is the set of all transcendental numbers.

I've seen a few proofs that are based on the statement $$(1)\ \ \mathbb{R}=T\cup \{algebraic\ numbers\}$$
which is simple enough to finish. HOWEVER, on the wikipedia page of algebraic/transcendental numbers it is strictly stated that both transcendentals/algebraics can be complex or real.

I was hoping somone with more knowledge can shed some light on me.

Edit for clairty: I see that (1) would imply that there are $|T|\geq|R|$ many trascendental numbers, but why would that inequality be strictly an equality?

Comment: Why is it a problem that transcendental and algebraic numbers can be complex?

Comment: In that case, all we have proven is that |T|≥|ℝ|, but not necessarily equal

Comment: You should start by defining whether your $T$ is the set of _real_ transcendental numbers or of _all_ transcendentals, real or complex.  The proof is true in either case since $|\mathbb{C}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ (and you should be able to easily prove that), but my guess is that the exercise is speaking of the set of transcendental _real_ numbers, in which case the statement you give is true and those proofs you've seen go through.

Comment: Also, you may be a little confused; your (1) implies that $|T|\leq |R|$, not that it's $\geq$.

Comment: the $T$ in (1) is restricted to its real parts in the proofs shown hence why I wrote $|T|\geq|R|$. Thanks however, I will prove $|C|=|R|$ and proceed from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are the real algebraic numbers (those that satisfy an even polynomial of odd degree over $\mathbb{Q}$) and the complex algebraic numbers (those that satisfy any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$). Recall the fact that ever polynomial has degree many roots. Now, how many polynomials can we write? (Answer: Only countably many  -- you should be able to show this). Since there are only countably many polynomials (over $\mathbb{Q}$), each corresponding to only finitely many real/complex numbers, we have that the real algebraic numbers and the complex algebraic numbers is the countable union of finitely sets, which you should know is also countable. Since transcendental numbers are those defined as "not" algebraic, we have 2 cases:

The real case is trivial (since $|\mathbb{R}|=2^{\aleph_0} > |\mathbb{N}|$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ minus a countable set is still $2^{\aleph_0}$)

The complex case is realizing that $|\mathbb{C}|=|\mathbb{R}|$, which then boils down to the argument above.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why but I thought that $|\mathbb{C}|> |\mathbb{R}|$

Comment: Some care must be taken in formulating questions about being able to _write down_ things. The question "How many polynomials can we write?" is a bit misleading. Not only can we _write_ a countable number of polynomials, but there _are_ a countable number of polynomials, too. To see why the question is misleading, consider the similar question "How many real numbers can we write?" Clearly, we can _write_ only a countable number of real numbers (including describing them with any kind of formulae, as we can do with π), but there _are_ uncountably many.